# Checking injectivity of piece-wise functions using differentiation

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have a function defined as follows:

$f:N \rightarrow N$ such that $ f(n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{n+1}{2},  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
\frac{n}{2}, & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$ for all $n \in N$

($N$ is the set of all natural numbers)

Now, I know that if a function is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing in its entire domain, it is injective. But here, I get $f'(n) = \frac{1}{2}$ for both definitions, so $f'(n)\geq 0$, and by that logic it has to be injective...?

But, I can clearly see that $f(1) = \frac{1+1}{2}=1$ and $f(2) = \frac{2}{2} = 1$, so it clearly isnt injective. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot differentiate a function defined on $\mathbb N$. However the real reason this method does not work is that the derivative condition only holds if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @player3236 ok, I figured as much. I clearly hadn't checked continuity and differentiability

Comment: @player3236 It is not clear how continuity are related to your comment: the function above is indeed continuous.

Comment: @ArcticChar Continuous on its domain, yes. As a subset of $\mathbb R$ though, the derivative cannot be taken. Or do you have a way to find the derivative of $f$?

Comment: Derivatives is only (possibly) defined at a point $x$ in the domain if $x$ is also a cluster point of the domain, so in this case one cannot speak of differentiability. But that is not related to continuity (that's why I am confused why you mention continuity in your comment) @player3236

Answer (score 1):

As @player3236 said, you can't take the derivative of a function defined over $\mathbb{N}$. You have to use the definition of injectivity. That is, if you have a function $$f:X\rightarrow Y$$ then $f$ is injective if: $$ \forall a,b\in X,\;\;f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$$
Start by assuming $f(n)=f(k)$ for some $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$, then try to show that $n=k$.